# SqlDataReader convert Binary(1) column to bool

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

We have a table which has a column `IsChecked` which has `Binary(1)` as the data type. Basically, it stores `0x00` or `0x01` to represent if that data row is checked.

I knew it would be better to use `Bit` as data type but there are lots of other modules associated with this table already so let's leave it the way it is for now.

I tried intuitive ways like

```
// _dr is the SqlDataReader
Convert.ToBoolean(_dr["IsChecked"]);
(bool)_dr["IsChecked"];
```

but it can't simply convert like that, then I tried some approaches I feel might work

```
bool.Parse(_dr["IsChecked"].ToString());
Convert.ToBoolean((byte)_dr["IsChecked"]);
Convert.ToBoolean((byte[])_dr["IsChecked"]);
Convert.ToBoolean((int)_dr["IsChecked"]);
```

But all above return me convert failed like

> Specified cast is not valid.

I check out how my colleague read this field in their module and it seems to require an output parameter which has `Bit` as the data type to bring the value out.

But there should be some way easier to do the same, right?
I just need to know the correct way to convert `_dr["IsChecked"]`.

Comment: Just change the column to a `Bit` datatype. If you need to create a new column of BitColumn and `Update Table Set BitColumn = BinaryColumn` then delete the BinaryColumn and rename.

Comment: What you are getting in `_dr["IsChecked"]` have you checked?

Comment: The problem is that the `binary` values that you are receiving are in `Hexadecimal` format(*as mentiond above `0x00` and `0x01`*). So, as a solution convert them first in `Integer` with a base of `16` then convert them into `Boolean` value like: `Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt16(_dr["IsChecked"].ToString(),16))`.

Comment: @sujithkarivelil It seems to be a byte[] or collection and [0]=0 or 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment you are getting the value in `_dr["IsChecked"]` is a *byte[] or collection and [0]=0* So you can use [`BitConverter.ToBoolean`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.toboolean?view=netframework-4.8) method,
which returns a Boolean value converted from the byte at a specified position in a byte array.

```
bool isChecked = BitConverter.ToBoolean(_dr["IsChecked"],0);
```

Try this [working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TIEGuM) as well. if the type of `_dr["IsChecked"]` is not  `byte[]` then you can cast them using `(byte[])_dr["IsChecked"]` before applying `BitConverter.ToBoolean`

Comment: The type of `_dr["IsChecked"]` is `object`, `byte[]` is the value it contains, so I need to `(byte[])_dr["IsChecked"] )` first as you mentioned in supplement.